# Youtube V3 Api not returning the latest results

Tags: ios, node.js, youtube, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I am making call to the uploads playlist on a channel. On my personal youtube feed it showed that the user uploaded a video "5 minutes ago" so I went to their api explorer and checked the return object of the uploads playlist. The latest video was the one that user uploaded before this one. Basically It didn't have the latest video in the response. I checked thirty minutes later and still not there. Is there anyway I can know on the backend when a user uploads a video right away?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29204271/are-upload-playlists-on-youtube-api-v3-purpsofully-slow-to-be-updated

Comment: Thanks, that was quite useful!